# Unique Presheaf of Algebras

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I have a question a definition in Lemma 7.1.12 (page 255) in Liu's "Algebraic Geometry": 
In Lemma 1.12 (above red line) there is postulated the existence of a (unique) presheaf of algebras $K_X ^{'} $ on $X$ containing $O_X$.

Here the excerpt:
[image]

That's not clear to me over WHICH rings these algebras are defined?

Intuitively I suppose that for open subsets $U$ of X he means $K_X ^{'} (U)$ 
as $O_X(U)$-algebras, but that's just my speculation ...
is that true?

Comment: Here "(pre-)sheaf of algebras" means *"(pre-)sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$-algebras."* You guessed it correctly.